# MySQL Monitor Change

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I have a column in a table which records the time which a certain value from another specific column, in the same table, was changed. I am using MySQL version 5.0.67.

This SQL is required for a booking system. For example, when a booking is inserted into the booking table, a confirmation column is filled with: B, when a client confirms a booking the value is changed to BC. How can I record the time which this change took place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very common approach is to use "audit" tables which are copies of original tables but with additional columns such as log_id, log_timestamp, log_user. Then you'd create INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE triggers on original tables which will insert copy of changed row into the audit table along with timestamp/db user information.

Here is one example of such implementation: [Using MySQL Triggers to Audit Field Changes from a Database Table](http://streetsmartingit.blogspot.com/2008/04/using-mysql-triggers-to-audit-field.html)

Comment: Glad to hear it might work for you. You'd want to exercise caution with this approach if your dataset is large/tables get frequently updated as in that case the audit tables will grow very quickly.